# psql how do you pg_dumpall to a remote server's folder

Tags: backup, remote-server, psql, pg-dump

I tried:

```
pg_dumpall > username@remoteServer:/mnt/glusterfs/backups/allDB.sql
```

... no success remotly  while backup works locally:

```
pg_dumpall > /home/backups/database/postgresql/allDB.sql
```

I am running psql 9.2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an ssh-style specifier as the target for a pipe in the shell.

If you want to send it over ssh to the remote server, you need to use standard I/O pipelines. The `ssh` command copies stdin on the local side to stdout on the remote side, acting as a pipe between the two servers, so you can just:

```
pg_dumpall | ssh username@remoteServer 'cat > /mnt/glusterfs/backups/allDB.sql'
```